# Acer Black Veriton M4630G freezes and cant access bios

Tags: windows-7, boot

I'm currently trying to fix my dads work computer and after 5 hours trying to figure out what's wrong, i still can't seem to fix it.

here's what happened.
after the PC was left overnight, my father rebooted the PC.
after the reboot, it will only just boot up Acer bios logo then it freezes up and i can't even access the BIOS.

so far here's what I've done.
- I tried removing the memory card and the PC continuously beeps.
- when i removed the hard drive, i can now access the BIOS but when i put the hard drive back it still freezes up after the acer bios logo.
- I have also replaced the CMOS battery with a new one.
- I replaced the hard disk with my working hard disk at home and it seems that if i use that hard drive it goes into a startup recovery loop.
- I also have tried to load my dads work hard drive on my home computer and it's behavior changed from boot logo freeze into a startup recovery loop.
- I have also already tried startup repair through DVD but it's not working.

here's the full specs of the PC.

Processor Type
Intel Core i5-4570 Quad-Core Processor
Hard Drive Capacity 
500 GB
Optical Drive
DVDRW (R DL) / DVD-RAM
Display Technology
None.
Memory Card Type
Media Card Reader
Watts
300 Watts
Processor Speed 
3.20 GHz
Color Category
Black
Maximum RAM Supported
32 GB
Connector Type
2 x Aux Audio, 1 x DisplayPort, 1 x DVI, 1 x Ethernet, 6 x USB 2.0, 4 x USB 3.0, 1 x VGA
Operating System
Windows 7 Pro OEM

PS the PC has no dedicated GPU.

Comment: " my dads work computer " - shouldn't that be best left to their IT department? At worst, they would be able to replace it.

Comment: the IT department is at the head office and it's pretty far from here  and besides if they will process a replacement it would take like a month or so and the experience is just what i needed to improve my knowledge